# Can we redirect one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to open a jsp page without accessing my servlete code. i.e. I neither have to input my url in (action="url") my jsp code nor have to access my Servlete code.

```
<form id="main" method="post" name="main" action="dpRegPost" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: response.sendRedirect() should do

Comment: Using Javascript, without submitting the form: `window.location = "theNewUrl.jsp"`.

Comment: is there some other way other than window.location? I have  to it through form.

Comment: So you want to submit the form, then send back a redirect in the response? If so, there's an answer for that already...

Comment: @Brain : `<jsp:forward page="relativeURL" />`Use this action tag to forward the request to another resource it may be a JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form id="main" method="post" name="main" action="" onsubmit="redirect(this);">
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>


function redirect(elem){
     elem.setAttribute("action","somepage.jsp");
     elem.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add javascript to your jsp file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "www.google.com";
</script>
```

or using jsp

```
<%

    response.sendRedirect("www.google.com");
%>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this

```
<jsp:forward page = "abc.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jstl taglibrary in your current jsp page.Make available the taglibrary using below code

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Use Following code in jsp to redirect

```
<c:redirect url="/xxx.jsp"/>
```

Comment: I have to do it through form friend :)

Comment: write the code in java script function as follows                  window.location.href = "/xxx.jsp";

Answer (score 1):

You can also call page directly with:

```
<jsp:redirect page="xyz.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use the following code to redirect on another page in js...

$('#abc_id').click(function() {
            updateSubContent("abc.jsp");
        });
```